# Letra ç no editor do VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, osx, microsoft, visual-studio-code

O cedilha "ç" sumiu no Visual Studio Code que utilizo no MacBook. Isso aconteceu faz algum tempo após uma atualização. Funciona em qualquer editor menos no VS Code. 
Alguém ja passou por isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia tentar explicar de outra maneira o seu problema? Não consegui compreender...

Comment: No MacBook, quando quero digitar a letra "ç", utilizo o atalho "option + c" pois ela não existe no teclado americano. Porém, quando preciso desta letra no VS Code, utilizo o atalho e nada acontece. Isso só está acontecendo no VS Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vá em: ( Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts ) e ao abrir a aba de configurações de teclas, abaixo do campo de pesquisa tem a opção de abrir em modo avançado o arquivo (keybindings.json) e edite-o adicionando o objeto abaixo:

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+c",
        "command": "-task.cancel",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+c c",
        "command": "-extension.colorHelper.convert",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+c p",
        "command": "-extension.colorHelper.pick",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

Resolveu comigo aqui esse problema o código acima!  Abs...

Comment: Obrigado mas aqui não resolveu. Ele fica esperando outra tecla pra completar alguma combinação. Ja tentei de tudo mas nada.

Comment: No VSCode, em Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts (como expliquei acima), a opção de abrir em modo avançado o arquivo (keybindings.json), não é necessário combinar nenhuma tecla. o código que citei acima basta colar no arquivo (keybindings.json) colando-o, pois nesse código o comando que bloqueia o cedilha é anulado: Veja no objeto "command" { 
        "key": "alt+c",                 
        "command": "-task.cancel",
        "when": "editorTextFocus" 
    }

Apenas cole o código no arquivo (keybindings.json) e salve. Nem precisei reiniciar o software.

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso. To colocando a imagem acima na pergunta. Veja a mensagem na status bar.

Comment: Estranho, pois tal mensagem não apareceu para mim. Bastou colar esse objeto com os parâmetros que resolveu. Talvez seu comando seja outro.

Faz o seguinte: No arquivo ( Default Keybindings ) que abre junto ao editar o ( keybindings.json ), pesquise na lista geral de atalhos,  o atalho ( alt+c ). Deve aparecer o comando que deve estar conflitando. Copie o objeto do atalho e cole no ( keybindings.json ). Apenas atente para o detalhe de adicionar um hífen no elemento "command" como no código exemplificado acima. Assim você anula o mesmo.

Comment: Resolveu aqui com esse código: Obrigado CodeInPixel Studios.

Resolvido quando adicionei estas linhas ao arquivo keybindings.json:

    [
        {
            "key": "alt+c",
            "command": "-task.cancel",
            "when": "editorTextFocus"
        },
        {
            "key": "alt+c c",
            "command": "-extension.colorHelper.convert",
            "when": "editorTextFocus"
        },
        {
            "key": "alt+c p",
            "command": "-extension.colorHelper.pick",
            "when": "editorTextFocus"
        }
    ]. Era um plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

- Abrir o VSCode
- Na barra superior, ir em: Code -> Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts
- No arquivo aberto, procure por "alt+c", que é o atalho usado pelo mac para fazer o "ç"
- Encontre a configuração que usa esse atalho na lista, no meu caso era o "markdown.extension.checkTaskList" e clique nele
- No campo de texto aberto, atribua uma nova keybiding para esse comando e aperte Enter. No meu caso, coloquei "ctrl+alt+c"

A imagem abaixo mostra o caminho feito para chegar na configuração de keybidings default do VSCode

[Caminho para configuração de atalhos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnuAW.png)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Para mim, funcionou assim, no *keybindings.json*:

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+c",
        "command": "",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esta solução foi a única que funcionou para mim (macOS Monterey 12.4, VSCode 1.68.0)